# Bootstrap local files, some pages not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap as a cdn, however now that I've changed over to local files some pages don't work. It works almost everywhere, just a few pages it doesn't. When I switch back to the cdn everything is fine again.

Here are my links.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="../static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And the CDN

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: You could at least tell us what doesn't work - we are not psychic...

Comment: It can be a version of bootstrap.

Comment: No need for the attitude DavidG, just giving you all the info I thought was necessary.

Comment: No, you gave us virtually no information.

Comment: Well the guy you were complaining about below actually gave me the right answer. So just relax and we'll all get through it together.

Comment: This issue was using ../ instead of just /

Comment: Well when you have a website with over 12 million questions, it's important to try to keep it as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ".." from the file location while you are using it locally... Also make sure the version of Bootstrap corresponds as CDN's update files regularly, especially MaxCDN.

Comment: It's true that MaxCDN updates regularly, but wouldn't the version number in the URL (`.../3.3.6/...`) prevent that sort of problem? Isn't that exactly what versioned URLs are for?

Comment: Yes I agree but we don't know if the files were obtained from the CDN or downloaded elsewhere. Its a precautionary measure to double check it.